# New and Create Action for Nested Model not saving user_id

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, stack-overflow

Alright I have three models...A User, a Collection, and a Design.

My Models =

User Model

```
 `has_many :collections
  has_many :designs, :through => :collections`
```

Collection Model

```
`belongs_to :user
 has_many: designs`
```

Designs Model

```
`belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :collection`
```

Alright when I try to create a collection all works well. All params get saved to the DB including the user_id associated with it using (current_user).

My problem comes in when i try to create a design (which belongs to a collection). When i create a new design the user_id is not getting stored

Here is my Designs controller for the new and create methods

Designs Controller:

```
`def new
   if signed_in? && current_user == @collection.user
     @user = current_user
     @collection = @user.collections.find(params[:collection_id])
     @design = @collection.designs.new
   else
     flash[:error] = "That's not your collection"
     redirect_to root_url
  end
end`

'def create
   @collection = current_user.collections.find(params[:collection_id])
   @design = @collection.designs.new(design_params)

   respond_to do |format|
     if @design.save
       format.html { redirect_to collection_designs_path(@collection), notice: 'Design was successfully created.' }
      format.json { redirect_to collection_designs_path(@collection) }
    else
      format.html { render 'designs/new' }
      format.json { render json: @design.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end`
```

Here is the form im using (minus the fields)

```
`<%= form_for [@collection, @design], :html => { :multipart => true, :class => "auth" } do |f| %>
   <fields are here>
 <% end %>`
```

Just to clarify, I can submit the form and the form works and the design gets created with the collection_id attached, but unfortunately the user_id is NOT getting associated with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not associated any user object with design. Try this is design controller.
In create action,

Design Controller

```
def create
   @collection = current_user.collections.find(params[:collection_id])
   @design = @collection.designs.new(design_params)
   @design.user = current_user

   respond_to do |format|
     if @design.save
       format.html { redirect_to collection_designs_path(@collection), notice: 'Design was successfully created.' }
      format.json { redirect_to collection_designs_path(@collection) }
    else
      format.html { render 'designs/new' }
      format.json { render json: @design.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end`
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe i left out <20 letters! It's always beneficial to have a fresh set of eyes take a look